# Trying to understand the operation sequence of macros

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
#define HEIGHT IS_IPHONE5 ? 568 : 480

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"HEIGHT: %d",HEIGHT);
    NSLog(@"HEIGHT: %d",HEIGHT+99);
}
```

Both of the logs above will result **568**. I'm guessing this is happening because of the sequence of the operations. Can any one give me a good explanation on this?

(I'm not looking for a solution or an alternative way doing the above. Just an explanation why this is happening)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
NSLog(@"hight: %d",HIGHT+99);
```

Will expand as

```
 NSLog(@"hight: %d",IS_IPHONE5 ? 568 : 480+99);
```

and then

```
NSLog(@"hight: %d",(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES) ? 568 : 480+99);
```

So it will yield `568`

**Solutions**:

```
NSLog(@"hight: %d",(HIGHT)+99);
```

or

```
#define HIGHT (IS_IPHONE5 ? 568 : 480)
```

I'll suggest to use second solution.

Comment: This is only part way there.

Comment: @rmaddy: yes, it'll further expand the other macro also. editing my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Macros like you have are simply replaced at compile time. Once your code is compiled, the code is just:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"hight: %d",(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES) ? 568 : 480);
    NSLog(@"hight: %d",(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES) ? 568 : 480+99);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Macros like you have"? Mind linking me to other types of macros?

Comment: Perhaps that was misleading wording. All macros get replaced at compile time but there are more complex macro syntax. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion and look under "Special macros and directives".